# Dynamic form in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm developing a CMS for a customer, it's all based on AngularJS with its controllers, views, services, etc.

**What I need is a pattern where a dynamically loaded script injects some data in an existing scope**.

Ok, in human words: **I have a form managed by a controller**. This form has several preset fields. These fields are managed by an array of the scope, something like:

```
$scope.fields = [
  { type: "text", name="first_name" },
  { type: "text", name="last_name" },
  { type: "email", name="email" }
];
```

The view prints dynamically the fields (i.e. it's a scaffolding).

When the customer log into the application I check if in his profile he has a custom script to load, if so the application appends a javascript to the DOM, the javascript file name is equal to the username of the logged user.

So, if the user is called "**darko**" and he has a custom script enabled, the application append this file to the DOM:

**/js/customers/darko.js**

Let's say that **darko has further fields to show (and save) inside the form**, how can I do that? I'd need to hook the controller so I can have access to its scope and then inject my fields. Something like:

```
var $scope = getUserFormScope();//some magic....
$scope.fields.push({ type: "text", name="skype" });
```

However, The form with further fields is just an example, what I really need, more generally, is a way to "hook controllers" and have access to theirs scopes.

Any idea?

### SOLUTION

I've finally used the method suggested by marfarma. The custom script contains one or more partial controllers named with the same name of the controller they want to extend prefixed by *Custom* word, then I extend my controllers with these partial controllers. For example, my app has a controller named PageController, inside this controller I check if a CustomPageController exists:

```
if (typeof CustomPageController == 'function') {
    angular.extend(this, CustomPageController($scope));
}
```

if so, I extend the main controller with the custom one.

Comment: When the user logs into the application why not broadcast an event then have the controllers load information particular to that user account? See "Scope Events Propagation" on this page: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope

Comment: what does `custom script enabled` mean? If all you ever do is pull user data should be straighforward

Comment: @drew_w thank you, this is a good idea and the documentation about scope is really interesting.

Comment: @charlietfl "custom script enabled" means that a user can have his own javascript file to load. This file can contains customizations of the cms, helper functions, custom messages etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a general way to "hook controllers" and have access to their scopes - mixin your hook code via angular.extend.

```js
function CustomUserController($scope) {
    // contents of this hook controller is up to you

    var _this = this;

    // Mixin instance properties.
    this.vocalization = getValue('vocalization',$scope.user);
    this.runSpeed = getValue('runSpeed'        ,$scope.user);

    // Mixin instance methods.
    this.vocalize = function () {
        console.log(this.vocalization);
    };

    // Mixin scope properties.
    $scope.color = color;

    // Mixin scope methods.
    $scope.run = function(){
        console.log("run speed: " + _this.runSpeed );
    };
}

function PageController($scope) {

    var _this = this;
    $scope.user; // this should be the current user obj, with key for custom script lookup

    // Mixin Custom Script into Controller.
    if (userService.hasCustomScript($scope.user)) {
        angular.extend(this, new CustomUserController($scope));
    }
}
```

As for your specific example, one way to insert arbitrary fields into a form is to build it dynamically.  I use a schema form directive that might work for your situation. Given a schema that defines the model properties, and an array that specified the items their order of inclusion, the directive lays out the form.

For example (see also this [working plunker, incl. add'l features](http://plnkr.co/edit/ySitXy2Y7Of0ytdaKqvl?p=info)):

```html
<form class="form-inline" name="form" novalidate role="form">
    <div class="row-fluid clearfix">
        <h2>Sample Form</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid clearfix">
        <hr> 
        <div class="span12">
            <fieldset class="span6">
                <schema-form-fields
                    fields="side1Fields"
                    model="model"
                    schema="modelSchema"
                    data="requestResult"
                    schema-list="schema">
                </schema-form-fields>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="span6">
                <schema-form-fields
                    fields="side2Fields"
                    model="model"
                    schema="modelSchema"
                    data="requestResult"
                    schema-list="schema">
                </schema-form-fields>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid clearfix">
        <button
            class="btn btn-primary span2 offset10"
            type="submit">
            Submit
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

```js
// example controller with dynamic form
app.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', 'schema', 'requestResult', 'dataService',
    function($scope, schema, requestResult, dataService) {

        $scope.modelSchema = schema.product;          
        $scope.model = {
            factoryDate: '20160506'
        };

        // field name arrays - one array per column in sample layout
        // insert elements into these and form should re-render
        // may require explicit watch to trigger update
        $scope.side1Fields = [
            'productName',
            'factoryDate'
        ];

        $scope.side2Fields = [
            'productType',
            'timeValue'
        ];  

        // ....  other controller code    
    }
]);
```

```js
// example schema
app.value('schema', {
    "product": {
        "type": "object",
        "title": "Product Schema",
        "properties": {
            "productType": {
                "type": "string",
                "title": "Product Type",
                "showLabel": true,
                "tooltip": "Product classification",
                "readonly": false,
                "required": true,
                "class": "custom-select",
                "enum": ['Bike', 'Car', 'Airplane', 'Glider', 'Stilts']
            },
            "productName": {
                "title": "Product Name",
                "showLabel": true,
                "type": "string",
                "tooltip": "A more descriptive name for the modeled structure.",
                "readonly": false,
                "required": true
            },
            "factoryDate": {
                "title": "Factory Date",
                "type": "string",
                "showLabel": true,
                "control": "date",
                "dateFormat": "yyyymmdd",  // TODO format as provided 
                "tooltip": "Date of manufacture.",
                "dateOptions": {
                    autoclose: true
                },
                "readonly": false,
                "required": true
            },
            "timeValue": {
                "title": "Time (HHMM)",
                "showLabel": true,
                "type": "string",
                "pattern": "([0-1]{1}[0-9]{1}|20|21|22|23)[0-5]{1}[0-9]{1}",
                "timeFormat": "hhmm",  // TODO format as provided 
                "tooltip": "Time entry.",
                "readonly": false,
                "required": true,
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Re-reading your question, it seems you already dynamically layout your form, so ignore the second half of the answer.

Comment: Hey, very interesting, thanks. I didn't know angular.extend I just don't understand how you register PageController as an angular controller. You mean something like: angular.module('myApp').controller(PageController) ?

Comment: btw, yes I already have a dynamic way to make forms, I save in my database a model made of "properties", each property can have a "type", a "default value", a "regexp validation", etc.

Comment: exactly, `angular.module('myApp').controller('PageController')` is your standard controller, and is defined for dependency injection (DI) - the mixin is just a function that follows the controller calling convention, but it's not defined for DI, instead called with a 'new' like any javascript prototype function -- but passing in the current $scope object.  Then extend copies the new object's properties back into the calling scope.

Comment: ok, but I need the opposite of your example, because the user loads a custom controller, so it's the custom controller that extends the default one, also because when the user log into the app, the default controller is already there, the custom controller is loaded later. But I think it doesn't affect the main concept. Tomorrow I'll try it, thanks.

Comment: In my example PageController is the default, CustomUserController is your user's custom controller and the PageController + CustomUserController combination (after mixin) is the controller that executes the view - I don't think that's opposite of what you wanted.  In any case, good luck.

Comment: I thought the opposite in the meaning that I wanted to extend PageController from the custom script so I tried to use angular.extend from the custom script but it couldn't work as I don't have $scope there. Nevermind because I used your method, so, inside my PageController I check if a function called "CustomPageController" exists (convention over customizations) and if so than I extend my PageController.